# Quick way to find out how much silence is at the start of an MP3?

Tags: audio, mp3

What's a quick and easy way to find out how much silence is at the start of an MP3? I know there's a lot that goes into that... I don't need anything too precise. Within 50 or so milliseconds is great.

Note that I don't want to remove the silence. I just want to find out the length of it.

Also, I need to do this with some 1000 files, so a scripting solution would be great.

Comment: What programming tools are at your disposal? What platform? Keep in mind that an mp3 decoder may add some samples at the beginning as part of the decoding process.

Comment: I'm fairly open on this front. I'm on a Mac doing iPhone development. My hope is that there is some command line tool already installed, some linux util I can download, some Ruby gem I can install and script with, or anything like that.

Comment: I don't know of any existing tool. I would do it in Matlab, but if you don't have Matlab it can be done in c, python,... the list is probably long. The steps would be decoding to raw data, and looking for the first non-zero sample, or the first rise above some threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Open it in Audacity, scale it so you get the resolution you want, and eyeball it.

Comment: Yep, I've done that, works great. I forgot a detail, which I've since edited the question to include. I need to do this with 1000 files.